# How to change Revit 2014 element name by API C#

Tags: c#, revit, revit-api

I want to change element name by API and I have the following code.

```
Reference r = docUI.Selection.PickObject(ObjectType.Element, "Please pick an element");
Element element = doc.GetElement(r.ElementId);

element.Name = "MyElement";
```

But why occured this error ? 'This element does not support assignment of a user-specified name.' 
Or should I change the name by another way ?

Please help!

Answer (score 3):

Element names can't be changed.  If you are actually looking to change the name of the element "type", that is editable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have to change the Element Type to change its Name.
Something like the following:

```
element.ChangeTypeId(anotherElementTypeId);
```

Answer (score 0):

The Name of an element is read-only and not supposed to be changed.